# Windows 8 WsHttpBinding

Tags: binding, windows-8, wshttpbinding

I just downloaded Visual Studio 2012 and I want to connect my wcf service which is written in .net4. I want to define a `WsHttpBinding` like

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
```

but the problem is the system does not recognize

```
WsHttpBinding binding = new WsHttpBinding()
```

or something like that. Does anyone know why not?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [list of WCF Bindings supported by a Metro Style App](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piyushjo/archive/2011/10/19/wcf-for-metro-apps-supported-functionality.aspx).  Ws-* does not appear to be currently supported.